# Why doesn't pytorch allow inplace operations on leaf variables?

Tags: python, pytorch

So if I run this code in Pytorch:

```
x = torch.ones(2,2, requires_grad=True)
x.add_(1)
```

I will get the error:

> RuntimeError: a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation.

I understand that Pytorch does not allow inplace operations on leaf variables and I also know that there are ways to get around this restrictions. What I don't understand is the philosophy behind this rule. Why is it wrong to change a leaf variable with inplace operations?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I understand it, any time you do a non-traditional operation on a tensor that was initialized with `requires_grad=True`, Pytorch throws an error to make sure it was intentional. For example, you normally would only update a weight tensor using `optimizer.step()`.

For another example, I ran into this issue when trying to update the values in a backprop-able tensor during network initialization.

```
self.weight_layer = nn.Parameter(data=torch.zeros(seq_length), requires_grad=True)
self.weight_layer[true_ids == 1] = -1.2
```

```
RuntimeError: a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation.
```

The problem is that, because `requires_grad=True`, the network doesn't know that I'm still initializing the values. If this is what you are trying to do, wrapping the update in a `torch.no_grad` block is one solution:

```
with torch.no_grad()
    self.weight_layer = nn.Parameter(data=torch.zeros(seq_length), requires_grad=True)
    self.weight_layer[true_ids == 1] = -1.2
```

Otherwise, you could just set `requires_grad=True` after you finish initializing the Tensor:

```
self.weight_layer = nn.Parameter(data=torch.zeros(seq_length))
self.weight_layer[true_ids == 1] = -1.2
self.weight_layer.requires_grad = True
```

Comment: if you modify self.weight_layer[...] inside with torch.no_grad(), wouldn't it set the "requires_grad=False" to self.weight_layer ?

Comment: Nope. The way that `torch.no_grad()` works, the `requires_grad` attribute on the `nn.Parameter` is never modified - even within the `torch.no_grad()` context.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to this is that, once autograd creates the graph, and we have created our tensors which are a input to the graph, autograd will construct and track each operation on your created tensor. Now, since this tensor has `requires_grad=True`, and let's say I do a weight update after `loss.backward()`, autograd is probably considering as a part of  the already created graph, which requires gradients.  This leads to the `RuntimeError: a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation.`
Autograd is confused that why is a tensor which is a part of the computational graph being used outside/being used for some other operations/initialization of it inplace and this is an an problem

if we simply place the code under a
`with torch.no_grad(): code here`
we disable the gradients, and hence there is essentially it signals to autograd that this operation is not a part of our dynamic graph updates.

PS: I will expand this answer by writing a blog of this on Medium